# Correct use of margin property to locate a logo to the right

Tags: html, css

Having html

```
<div class="wrapper" id="top">
  <div class="main-logo bg-yellow-niza">
    <img src="http://eurekavi.com/car/images/logo.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

And Css

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-logo {
  background: #707070;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.main-logo img {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It correctly displays a logo at the center of screen, However I want to locate it at 200 px before the right corner.

[image]

I have tried modifying `left: 0; and right: 0;` values but I am not able to locate the logo some px before the outer right.

How to do it?

please take a look at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dt2w6gkr/)

Comment: Change position: absolute to position:relative. Then changing left:0; to left:200px for example will shift the logo. You want the position relative to the wrapper so that you can adjust for screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
.main-logo {
  background: #707070;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

to this:

```
.main-logo {
  background: #707070;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  right: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

The difference is settings the 'right' position to 200px, removing 'left : 0;' and removal of the margins.

Answer (score 1):

You can try floating the `.main-logo` div to the right and then using margin to force it away from the corner of the containing div.

```
.main-logo {
  background: #707070;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 9999;
  float: right;
  margin: 200px 200px 0 0;
}
```

Here's modified fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eroche/d0xjfbuk/

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
.main-logo img{
float: right
}
```

Or

```
.main-logo img{
display: inline-block
}
```

**Update**
I would simplify your code. Much of it you do not need and some you should probably let the browser handle because they might cause problems in the long run.

In your HTML set your height and width. It's 508 compliant and the "correct" place for it.

```
<div class="wrapper" id="top">
  <div class="main-logo bg-yellow-niza"
<img src="http://eurekavi.com/car/images/logo.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

In your CSS:

I would define the with that I want all of my wrapped element to be contained in here. If I want the container to be 100% then I wouldn't do the margin 0 auto. Or if you just want your content to fill the page then you don't event have to give the wrapper any styles, you'd just let the inner content set the dimensions.

```
.wrapper {
}
```

The height of this area is set by the height and width attributes in the HTML img tag. You could add some padding if you would like the contents inside to have some room. But you don't need most of this. P.S. The z-index could cause issues in the future if you self assign it. It may be best to let the browser do it unless you are sure you need to.

Just sets the background color.

```
.main-logo {
  background: #707070;
  /* not needed
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  */
}
```

Now just set your Inge to float right.

```
.main-logo img {
  float: right;
/* not needed
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
*/
}
```